# Difference between Dnsmasq and Dnsmasq-base

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I want to set up a DNS and DHCP server to bypass the loopback restriction of my internet provider. I wanted to install Dnsmasq but can't install It because of conflicts with Dnsmasq-base.
So my questions are :

- What are the differences between Dnsmasq and Dnsmasq-base?
- Can we set up what I want with Dnsmasq-base?
- If yes, how? If no, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Dnsmasq depends on dnsmsq-base, not conflicts with it. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dnsmasq

Answer (score 2):

1. Difference
   `dnsmasq` package require `dnsmasq-base` package as dependecy
   See packages details for [dnsmasq](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/dnsmasq) and [dnsmasq-base](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/dnsmasq-base)
   If your Ubuntu setup has some package conflicts, see how to resolve it:
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure
2. Feature dns and dhcp
   Of course yes, dnsmasq is made that for
3. How to...
   Simply as docs describe it :)
   You asked quite same question earlier, some answers where posted. 
   See those too:
   [Configuring DHCP-Server using dnsmasq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550780/configuring-dhcp-server-using-dnsmasq)
   [home server DNS with dnsmasq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093088/home-server-dns-with-dnsmasq)
   [How to Add dnsmasq and keep systemd-resolved (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032450/how-to-add-dnsmasq-and-keep-systemd-resolved-18-04)
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Comment: Yes thank you I know I have posted a quite same question before. However, any answer solved my problem ; I am still unable to install Dnsmasq I don't know why. So I can't apply any Tuto from the links I received...

Comment: You should try this at first : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure